# VS Code REST Client Extension: How to access nested response headers?

Tags: http-headers, vscode-extensions, response-headers, vscode-restclient

I'm trying to access 'nested' headers with the REST Client extension for VS Code.
I defined a **GET CSRF_Token** request that stores the "Set-Cookie" header inside a `@token_response` variable.

However the header looks like this:

```
'csrftoken=aGHuGkRbApH3qAksHHR3uaOKG0eZsYne; expires=Wed, 22 Nov 2023 08:40:05 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax'
```

---

I already tried to access it with something like:

```
@csrf_token = {{token_response.0.split(';').0.split('=').1}}
```

and

```
@csrf_token = {{token_response.//[0].//split(';')[0].//split('=')[1]}}
```

But this does not seem to be the correct syntax.
Also the [documentation](https://github.com/Huachao/vscode-restclient#request-variables) does not contain any hints on that yet, sadly.

**Now my question is:**

Is there a way to only extract the part of the header that contains the value of the "csrftoken" key?
And if so, how?

---

Here is my code:

```http
# Get CSRF Token
# @name getToken

GET http://{{host}}/api/csrf_token

@token_response = {{getToken.response.headers.Set-Cookie}}
@csrf_token = {{token_response}}


######


# Edit existing xyz
PATCH http://{{host}}/api/xyz/1
content-type: application/json
x-csrftoken: {{csrf_token}}
origin: http://{{host}}

{
    "name": "some name"
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance! :)